# Product Rule for Derivatives

Tags: calculus

So my teacher introduced the fact that the derivative of a product is not the product of the derivatives. However, I thought the derivative was just a type of limit. If the limit of a product is the product of the limits, why isn't the same true for the derivative?

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)$ is defined as $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$. What happens when you let $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$?

Comment: It actually makes more sense when I think of it that way, I didn't really observe what would happen using the definition of the derivative enough. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of the product $fg$ is not a product of limits defining derivatives, it is

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)}{h}$$

There is no way to write this as a product of a limit involving $h_1 \to 0$ and $f$ and a limit involving $h_2 \to 0$ and $g$.